# test zero correlation coefficient

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Is there any commonly used method to test the zero correlation between $X$ and $Y$ using the sample correlation coeffcient from two samples $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^n$ and $\{y_k\}_{k=1}^n$?

In another word, if $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^\top$ and $\boldsymbol{y}=(y_1,\dots,y_n)^\top$ are two standardized vectors, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=0$ and $\sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}=1$, is there any method to numerically judge $\boldsymbol{x}\perp \boldsymbol{y}$?

Actually $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $\boldsymbol{y}$ are two observed noisy data vectors, so I do not think it is appropriate to use $\boldsymbol{x}^\top \boldsymbol{y}=0$ as the criterion.

Comment: You coukd get a null distribution by using a permutation test  approach ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, any article I can refer to?

Comment: Perhaps this Q&A http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61026/can-p-values-for-pearsons-correlation-test-be-computed-just-from-correlation-co?rq=1

Comment: In Efron's book about the bootstrap, bootsrapping the corelation coefficient is the first example.  For permutation methods:  https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1113832732     Else, for a more useful answer, you shoukd tell us the context of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your observations follow a bivariate normal distribution, there's a test based on t-statistic for the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Using_the_exact_distribution) which gives the test statistic
$$
t = r \sqrt{\frac{n-2}{1-r^2}}.
$$
This has a t-distribution with $n-2$ degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

If your x and y are reasonably normal and $n$ is big enough, you can use the `cor.test` function in `R`, like this:

```
x <- runif(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
cor.test(x, y)
```